# flask-mail SMTPServerDisconnected error on EC2 with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, email, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04, flask-mail

I have a flask app using flask-mail to send out emails, using the same mail setting, I can successfully send out emails locally from my MacBook Pro. But when I deploy the same code with same email setting on EC2 on Ubuntu14.04, I cannot send emails and got the following error:

```
send: 'ehlo flasks-app-server1.localdomain\r\n'
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/srv/www/flasky/app/email.py", line 9, in send_async_email
    mail.send(msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_mail.py", line 415, in send
    with self.connect() as connection:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_mail.py", line 123, in __enter__
    self.host = self.configure_host()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_mail.py", line 142, in configure_host
    host.starttls()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 642, in starttls
    self.ehlo_or_helo_if_needed()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 542, in ehlo_or_helo_if_needed
    if not (200 <= self.ehlo()[0] <= 299):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 413, in ehlo
    self.putcmd(self.ehlo_msg, name or self.local_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 341, in putcmd
    self.send(str)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 333, in send
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected('please run connect() first')
SMTPServerDisconnected: please run connect() first
```

I have googled this for about two hours and could not find a solution. Any help, please? Thanks!!

Comment: Do you have a smtp server configured on your ec2 instance?

Comment: I am using AWS SES - it's working locally when I start the server using `python manage.py runserver`

Comment: Could you include your code to show what you're doing?  It would be fruitful to see your config.  Stating you're using SES doesn't help if we can't see how you're calling the smtp server from your code.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out. I AWS SES needs to verify the email for different region. I did not do that for the new region I am using. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I AWS SES needs to verify the email for different region. I did not do that for the new region I am using.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by opening port for SMTPS : 465 both on security group and the machine.